# GridSearchCV for Multiples Models

Tags: pipeline, gridsearchcv

I would like to run different models using GridSearchCV.

```
models = {
"RandomForestRegressor": RandomForestRegressor(),
"AdaBoostRegressor": AdaBoostRegressor(),}
params = {
"RandomForestRegressor": {"n_estimators": [10, 50, 75], "max_depth": [10, 20, 50], "max_features": ["auto","sqrt","log2"]},
"AdaBoostRegressor": {"n_estimators": [50, 100],"learning_rate": [0.01,0.1, 0.5],"loss": ["linear","square"]},}
```

Comment: Please elaborate for the readers what are you working with, what is the issue you are facing and what is your expectation. Spend some time to design a question which will help others to understand clearly

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is helpful, but perhaps just add a parameter to your "create_model" function. FOr example, here is a very basic create_model function that uses the activation function as its argument as the parameter that GridsearchCV is trying to help you tune.

```
def create_model(activation_fn):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=feats, activation=activation_fn,
                 kernel_initializer='normal'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation=activation_fn))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['mean_squared_error','mae'])
    return model
```

Now what you can do is modify this to have a second argument called model_type (or whatever you want to call it).

```
def create_model(model_type = 'rfr'):
       if model_type == 'rfr':
           ......
       elif model_type == 'xgb':
           .......
       elif model_type == 'neural_network':
           .......
```

Then in your params dictionary that is fed into the GridsearchCV that you call, you just give the model_type key a list of models that you want to tune (optimize over). Just make sure that within each block of code under a given "if" statement that you put in the proper code to create your desired model.